# Run Program on boot

Tags: raspbian, python

I want to run a program continuously on RPi but the problem is power off. Once it is turned off and then when I turn it ON i have to do all the process of login in and running the program again. What should I do to avoid it. How can I put a program on auto run?

Comment: This will have been covered before. Search for 'systemd'.

Comment: There are many posts about running programs on boot. As you have not described the program it is difficult to make a recommendation. There are many ways of doing this. You can make a `systemd` service but it is probably simpler to create a `cron` job to run on reboot.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! This question has been closed a duplicate. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/auto-running-programs

Relevant part:

> ## Auto running terminal applications (non GUI)
>
> First ensure your program is executable by finding it in the file manager.  Right click
> on the file and select properties.  Select the permissions tab, check
> the ‘Make the file executable’ box and press OK.  Or from the command
> line use:
>
> sudo chmod +x /home/pi/projects/my_project.a Or using a different tool
> set its chmod to 755 (rwxr-xr-x).  It doesn't matter if the user is
> root.
>
> #### Doesn't work?
>
> *We've found that when copying a new file to the rpi using WinSCP, changing its properties to 755 and verifying all is OK that if we kill
> the power and power up again the executable doesn't run.  However if
> we use sudo reboot at the command line it works as it should.  It
> seems there is some sort of caching action going on so after doing
> this use sudo reboot the first time rather than cycling the power!*
>
> You can setup the auto run using a script (see [here](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/scripts)), or you can do it
> directly by editing the rc.local file:
>
> sudo nano /etc/rc.local
>
> After the initial comments (lines beginning with '#') add the
> following lines:
>
> ## Auto run our application sudo /home/pi/projects/my_project.a & "sudo" assumes you want your application run with root user privileges
>
> (remove if not) and the "&" says do it in the background.
>
> Save it by pressing Ctrl+X, " Y", ENTER
>
> Re-boot your RPi and it will run.